# how to do conditional calculation with strange requirement

Tags: r, if-statement

I have strange problem with calculation, and I am not sure what I should do. I have a data that looks like this:
[image]

and I need to sort by ID and Date at first,which I did. Then i need to find the baseline date, only if duration for that date is <=0 and closest to 0, that one can be used as baseline, then I need to calculate usable=current score/baseline date score. so the final results should look like this:

[image]

What should I do? How can I check the oldest day and build "usable" to use the score/oldest score?

The codes for sample data are:

```
ID <-c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2")
Date<- c("4/19/2018","7/27/2018","8/24/2018","9/21/2018","10/19/2018","12/14/2018","1/11/2019","1/24/2019")
Duration <- c("-13","-7","95","142","2","36","75","81")
score <- c("0.06","0.071","0.054","0.0258","0.0208","0.0448","0.0638","0.0227")

Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Date, Duration, score)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns in 'Sample.data' are all `character` class as the values were quoted (used R 4.0.0.  If it was < R 4.0, `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` by default), so we used `type.convert` to change the class based on the values automatically, then before we do the `arrange` on 'ID', 'Date', convert the 'Date' to `Date` class (in case there are some inconsistency in the original data with respect to the order), after grouping by 'ID', create the new column 'Useable' with an `if/else` condition to return the standardized 'score' with the `first` value of 'score' or `else` return `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
Sample.data <- Sample.data %>% 
     type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
     mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>% 
     arrange(ID, Date) %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     mutate(Useable = if(first(Duration) <=0) c(NA, score[-1]/first(score))
                 else NA_real_)
Sample.data
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID Date       Duration  score Useable
#  <int> <date>        <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1 2018-04-19      -13 0.06     NA   
#2     1 2018-07-27       86 0.071     1.18
#3     1 2018-08-24       95 0.054     0.9 
#4     1 2018-09-21      142 0.0258    0.43
#5     2 2018-10-19        2 0.0208   NA   
#6     2 2018-12-14       36 0.0448   NA   
#7     2 2019-01-11       75 0.0638   NA   
#8     2 2019-01-24       81 0.0227   NA
```

Comment: Thanks for more details. What if we have "not reported" in score col. how can we do the calculation. I tried and it `non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: @Stataq you can coerce it to numeric `mutate(score = as.numeric(score))` and the non-numeric will be automatically converted to `NA` with a friendly warning (assuming `character` class.  If it is factor `mutate(score = as.numeric(as.character(score)))`

Comment: Another question: after we do above calculation, if I check sample.data in Environment, I won't see `Usable` in it. Same if I use `names(Sample.data`.  And I will need to do `Sample.data<-Sample.data ` in order to save it. Is it normal, why? Or I did sth wrong in the process.

Comment: @Stataq yes, you need to assign as it won't update the original object by default.  If you need to update, then instead of pipe `%>%` use the magrittr operator `%<>%`

Comment: Thanks so much. Never know that I can use `%<>%`.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again. the case is more complex now. If we have two duration<0, and I can only use the bigest negative duration for baseline, what should I do.  I tried `Baseline <- function(x) which(x == max(x[x < 0]))` and then Duration[Baseline(Duration)],etc.  But codes not running. I am lost again.

Comment: @Stataq When you say biggest negative duration.  Did you meant `min` instead of `max` because `max(c(-15, -30))` is `-15`

Comment: Yes, the closest to 0 one.

Comment: @Stataq Can you please post as a new question so that it would be more easier to understand